# Spin generator of massless fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-spin, spinors, poincare-symmetry

How can I derive an expression for the spin generator $S^{\mu\nu}$ of massless fields (preferably fermions) and show, in this way, that the $S^{0i},\ i=1,2,3$ components of the spin generator vanish??

Comment: Worked out [PL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli–Lubanski_pseudovector) for massless fermions?

Comment: $S^{i0}=0$ is not a Lorentz invariant statement. It is a common condition (the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition) imposed on the intrinsic angular momentum for massive particles in their *rest frame*. As massless particles have no rest frame, you  need to specify the four momentum. The wili article              https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathisson–Papapetrou–Dixon_equations has some useful info for the massive case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CosmasZachos. I am studying now about the Pauli-Lubansky operator and I really find that very helpful. Thanks. However, from another point of view, something is not clear. For example, the spin generator $S^{\mu\nu}$ appears to be generationg the boosts and rotations of the spinor field $\psi$. From what I understand, by representing $S^{\mu\nu}$ as $\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$, one can recover the three dimensional spinor transformation matrix in the rest frame and this is our motivation for doing so (correct me if I am wrong about that please).

Comment: So, as far as $S^{ij}$ is concerned, I kind of realize why it has that form. Moreover, due to that fact, the direct consequence is that $S^{0i}=-\frac{i}{2}[\gamma^{0},\gamma^{i}]$!! In the massless case though, the way I understand it, $S^{0i}$ has to be zero. I can not see a mathematical justification for that! I think this is the essence of my question! Or shall I be accepting that the $S^{i0}=0$ should be a requirement coming from the masslessness of the fermions/spinning fields??

Comment: @mikestone thank you for your response. I have seen the condition from the wikipedia page and some articles and they also seem helpful in understanding that $S^{0i}=0$ is true in the rest frame for massive particles. Does the the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition hold in the massless case as well??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that while the total angular momentum
$$
M_{\mu\nu}= x_\mu p_\nu - x_\nu p_\mu +S_{\mu\nu}
$$
about the point $x=0$
is well defined, the seperation between the orbital part  and the intrinisic angular momentum $S_{\mu\nu}$ depends on the choice of "where" the particle is, and this is frame-dependent when a particle has spin. For a massive particle one can choose the energy centroid in the particle's rest frame as "$x$" and this choice imposes the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition. For a massless partcile  there is no rest frame and the particl'es position is always frame dependent. The advantage of using the totally antisymmetric Pauli-Libanki tensor  $S_{\lambda\mu\nu}$ (invented by Myron Maththison and converted into a vector  $S_\alpha = \epsilon_{\alpha\lambda\mu\nu}S_{\lambda\mu\nu}/6$  by Lubanski) is that
$$
S_{\lambda\mu\nu}= p_\lambda M_{\mu\nu}+ p_\mu M_{\nu\lambda}+ p_\nu M_{\lambda\mu} 
$$
is that $x$ drops out in this combination and
$$
S_{\lambda\mu\nu}= p_\lambda S_{\mu\nu}+ p_\mu S_{\nu\lambda}+ p_\nu S_{\lambda\mu}. 
$$
For a massive particle one can recover $S_{\mu\nu}$ for the postion $S_{\mu\nu}= p^\lambda S_{\lambda\mu\nu}/m^2$, but for massless particles you have to divide by zero.

There is some  discussion of the physics of this  in our paper *Wigner translations and the observer-dependence of the position of masslesss spinning particles* Phys. Rev. Lett. 114, 210402 (2015) (arXiv:1501.04586) and in *Berry phase, Lorentz covariance, and anomalous velocity for Dirac and Weyl particles* (arxiv.org:1406.0354).

I think I should also add some stuff about where the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition on  the spin comes from. The following is taken from Misner Thorn and Wheeler (MTW).

Work in flat space and suppose that the we have a conserved and symmetric energy-momentum tensor:
$$
\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0, \quad T^{\mu\nu}=T^{\nu\mu}.
$$
Let $x_{\rm A}^\mu$ be a space-time event, $\Sigma$ a spacelike surface, and define the angular momentum about $x_{\rm A}$ by
$$
M^{\mu\nu}_{\rm A} = \int_\Sigma\left\{(x^\mu-x_{\rm A}^\mu)T^{\gamma\nu}- (x^\nu-x_{\rm A}^\nu)T^{\gamma\mu}\right\}d\Sigma_\gamma
$$
Then (MTW, page 161)  $M^{\mu\nu}_{\rm A} $ is a tensor and independent of the choice of  the choice of  $\Sigma$.

We now choose a lab  frame and define the *mass-centroid*  $X^i_{\rm L}$ in that frame by
$$
\left\{\int_{t=\rm const.} T^{00}d^3x \right\}\,X^i_{\rm L}= \int_{t=\rm const.} x^iT^{00}d^3x.
$$
Note that
$$
\partial_t  \int T^{00}d^3x =  \int \partial_0 T^{00}d^3x = - \int \partial_j T^{j0}d^3x=0,
$$
and
$$
\partial_t  \int x^i T^{00}d^3x =  \int  x^i\,\partial_0 T^{00}d^3x =   -\int  x^i\,\partial_j T^{j0}d^3x=  \int \delta^i_j \,T^{j0}d^3x= p^i.
$$
So, differentiating its definition with respect to $t$, we read off that the ordinary three-velocity of the centroid is
$$
\dot {\bf X}_{\rm L}= {\bf p}/E.
$$
Here
$$
E= \int T^{00}d^3x, \quad p^i =   \int  T^{0i}d^3x.
$$

Now take  $\Sigma$ to be the lab-frame  surface $t=$const with $x^\mu_{\rm A}$ a point in that surface. Then
$$
M^{i0}_{\rm A} = \int_\Sigma\left\{(x^i-x_{\rm A}^i)T^{00}- (x^0-x_{\rm A}^0)T^{0i}\right\}d^3x\nonumber\\
= (X^i_{\rm L}-x^i_{\rm A})E.\nonumber
$$
(The second term  is zero because $x^0- x^0_{\rm A}$  is zero everywhere in the integral.)
Thus $M^{i0}_A$ is zero when ${\rm A}$ is the centroid in the lab frame.  If we replace the lab frame with a frame having four-velocity $v^\mu$ we have that
$M^{\mu\nu}_{\rm A} v_\nu=0$ if and only if ${\rm A}$ is the mass centroid in that frame.

Define the *centre of mass* $X^i_{\rm CM}$ to be the mass-centroid in the frame where $p^i=0$, and the *intrinsic angular momentum*  $S^{\mu\nu}$ to be the angular momentum about the centre of mass.  Thus $S^{\mu\nu}p_\nu=0$ and we automatically have the Tulczyjew-Dixon  condition.